# Displaying all data in database if that data exists in another database in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two models, `SelectDate` and `Log`, I'm trying to display a selected date from the calendar control if that date is present in the `Log` database. i.e if `2017-10-08` is selected and it is present in the log database, display all instances of `2017-10-08` from the database. Here's how far I've gone.

```
public class Log
{
    public int LogID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Logout { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

public class SelectDate
{
    public int SelectDateID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string SelectedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The controllers, `CalendarDetails` is to display the proposed problem:

```
public ActionResult SelectDate(string username, SelectDate date, Log logdate)
{
    db.SelectDates.Add(date);
    db.SaveChanges();
    var getdate = from l in db.Logs
                  from sd in db.SelectDates
                  where (l.Date == sd.SelectedDate)
                  select l;
    if (getdate != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("CalendarDetail");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public ActionResult CalendarDetail(string username)
{
    var logTimes = db.Logs.Include(a => a.Employee);
    return View(logTimes.ToList());
}
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is the Logic flawed?

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Are you getting any error? What unexpected behavior you are getting with this code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the problem is it displays all the dates including the ones not selected i.e 2017-10-06 to 2017-10-08

Comment: Why do you redirect to `CalendarDetail` after filtering the `Logs` from the `SelectedDate` into `var getdate`? It looks like `CalendarDetail` just returns all `Logs` without the filtering in `SelectedDate`.

Comment: @Poosh that's exactly my problem, it just returns all the `Log`, I thought it would only return date where the selected date was the same as date in log. I don't know how to get only selected date, say if selected date was **2017-10-08** and it exists multiple times in db column `Date` it gets all **2017-10-08**

Comment: @Poosh and it exists multiple times in db column `Date` it gets all **2017-10-08**. and pls  how do I return `Logs` with filtered `SelectedDate` from `CalenderDetail`?

Comment: Do you need `string username` in `CalendarDetail`? If you passed `SelectDate date` you'd be able to apply the same filtering to the `Logs` that you're doing in `SelectDate`.

Comment: @Poosh I tried it, but it's still displaying all dates

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, does `getdate` have the correct dates? Your query looks right to me, but maybe you'll see some records in `getdate` that you aren't expecting and can filter it further.

Comment: @Poosh I just did what u asked, and set a breakpoint at `getdate` but the value is null... I don't understand why.

Comment: Where was your breakpoint? It will be null if it wasn't set on the line `if (getdate != null)` or after. Also, maybe the `date` parameter getting passed into `SelectDate(string username, SelectDate date, Log logdate)` is null; that might be worth checking too.

Comment: @Pooh Ya, actually, it shows that the `date` parameter passed is `null`. how do i remedy that?